# NetLogo, How do I save to file and load from file data entered into an extraWidget menu?

Tags: netlogo

Like the title said I'm trying to figure out how to save to file and load from file data entered into the extraWidget menu? I'd appreciate any assistance.

Comment: what's an extraWidget menu?

Comment: eXtraWidget, https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets , is a Netlogo extension that creates an additional interface tab in Netlogo. In effect it creates a dynamic GUI for Netlogo where users can enter data that the model can execute.. I believe it was created by Nicolas Payette

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that by "data entered into the eXtraWidget menu", you mean the values entered in the widgets appearing on an eXtraWidget tab.

If that's the case, it's fairly easy to do using the [`xw:export`](https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets/wiki/Primitives#xwexport) and [`xw:import`](https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets/wiki/Primitives#xwimport) primitives.

Suppose you have a very simple `xw` interface, like this:

```
extensions [ xw ]

to startup
  xw:clear-all
  xw:create-tab "t" [ xw:set-title "Menu" ]
  xw:create-multi-chooser "mc" [
    xw:set-items ["a" "b" "c" "d"]
  ]
end
```

That would give you an extra tab like this, with a "multi-chooser" in which you can select multiple letters ("a" and "c" in this example):

[image]

To export the whole interface and its content to a JSON file, you can simply call:

```
xw:export "menu.json"
```

and then recover the widgets and their values at any time with:

```
xw:clear-all
xw:import "menu.json"
```

You need to call `xw:clear-all` because `xw:import` will otherwise warn you that those widgets already exists.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas, can you save just the contents of the widgets without saving the entire menu?

Comment: Sure, but you would have to do this "manually" by using [`xw:get`](https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets/wiki/Primitives#xwget) to extract the values and the [`csv` extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html) to save and then load them back using [`xw:set`](https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets/wiki/Primitives#xwset).